# Salesforce/Apex, Why is TestDataFactory class included on code-coverage percentage?

Tags: testing, salesforce, apex

Now I'm making Apex test case for clearing code-coverage.

Used normal code following like,

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.198.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_utility_classes.htm

**TestDataFactory**

```
@isTest
public class TestDataFactory{
    public List<Account> createAccounts(){
        // data create...
        return accounts;
    }
    // data create methods...
    .
    .
    .
}
```

**MyTestClass**

```
@isTest
private class MyTestClass {
    static testmethod void test1() {
        TestDataFactory.createAccounts();
        // Run some tests
    }
    // other testmethods
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Number of lines of my TestDataFactory class is 100lines, and MyTestClass  100lines is test case logic is already completed code cover.

Therefore, 100 lines / 200 lines.
Code coverage is 50%.

Because code coverage of TestDataFactory class is 0%.

How can I solve it?

I'm sorry for poor English. Thank you for reading it.

Answer (score 1):

It works as expected. Shortly,

> Including code other than test methods in an @isTest annotated class will cause these lines to be counted in the overall code coverage numbers

Please, check [Why is a Test class evaluated as part of the Organization’s Code Coverage?](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Why-is-a-Test-class-evaluated-as-part-of-the-Organization-s-Code-Coverage&language=en_US)

I suggest, you remove @isTest from TestDataFactory class, to not confuse anyone. It will be covered with 100% as you use all methods in tests.

Comment: Awesome! It's the solution that I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: I know this is old post, by removing @isTest TestDataFactory class test coverage is 100%, but what about ```Test classes (classes that are annotated with @isTest) are excluded from the code coverage calculation``` we miss this isn't it? any other ideas to use @isTest and get code coverage 100% ?